# JavaScript - set class properties dynamically inside class method

Tags: javascript, class

This is a beginner's question and the context doesn't really matter, and neither whether it makes sense at all.

I want to create class properties with dynamic names *within a method of the class*. Essentially something like this (the code does not work, of course):

```
class Trial {
    set_dynamic_property(name, value) {
        this.setAttribute(name, value)
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You want to make class property or object property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

```js
class Trial {
    set_dynamic_property(name, value) {
        this[name] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I thought I had tried exactly this, but I must have messed up something.

Comment: Great to hear that. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem. 